# Pass pointer to a literal direct to a function

Tags: c

Given the following piece of C code:

```
void calc(int *value)
{
   // do something with value
}


int main(void)
{
    int i;

    i = 10;
    calc(&i);
}
```

Is it possible to get rid of setting up `i` and pass directly `10` to function `calc`? If yes, how can this be done?

Example of what I have in mind (which doesn't work):

```
calc( (int *) 10);
```

Comment: can `calc` be changed to need just an `int`?

Comment: @antiihaapala the duplicate you reported is as old as C89. In it everybody refers to compound literals (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) as struct or union and don't seems to be aware why it works. I have added my answer there, but I think that this question should be reopen.

Comment: Note well that the correct term is *constant* not literal in C.

Comment: This is not a trick nor impossible. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564701/pointer-to-literal-value/50273726#50273726

Comment: @Frankie_C negative, that one is a duplicate of this, the fact that it asks for the exact same thing.

Comment: @Bathsheba your choice to reopen is somehow strange, the duplicate look perfect...

Comment: @Stargateur: that duplicate targets an old C standard. If you feel strongly ask the mods to merge the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's impossible to have a pointer to a constant in C.

**UPD:** however it seems that there is [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3443883/1201488) using a <s>struct</s> *compound literals* syntax (thanks to @antti-haapala for the correction). Try this:

```
calc(&(int){10});
```

Comment: this is *not* a struct, but exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: This is a pointer to a variable - the variable happens to be anonymous and in-place. You can assign to these as well, e.g. `(int){ 5 } = 6;`.

Comment: **This is not a trick**. It is a compound literal as per:C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011):
6.5.2.5 Compound literals (p: 85-87)
C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999):
6.5.2.5 Compound literals (p: 75-77). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564701/pointer-to-literal-value/50273726#50273726. And the answer is wrong. It is possible.