# What does this statement about pointer operators mean? "& can be used only with a variable, * can be used with variable, constant or expression."

Tags: c, pointers

'Address of' operator gives memory location of variables. So it can be used with variables.

I tried compiling this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=889,*j,*k; 
    j=&889; 
    k=*6422296;

    printf("%d\n",j);
    return 0;
}
```

It showed this error `error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand` for `j=&889`.
And I was expecting this `error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')|` for `k=*6422296`.
6422296 is the memory location of variable i.

Can someone give examples of when '*' is used with constants and expressions?

P.S:- I have not yet seen any need for this But....
All constants in a program are also assigned some memory. Is it possible to determine their address with &? (Just wondering).

Comment: You can't take the address of a number. You can take the address of a variable, for example `&i`. Similarly, you can't dereference an integer.

Comment: It is not true that `&` can be used only with a variable.  It is true that `&` can be used only with an lvalue.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273726/1092820) for an example.    And for your question about dereferencing literal addresses, this may be something you would do in a very specific environment where you know certain addresses are available for certain reasons like if you were writing code for a microprocessor on hardware with very specific memory layout.

Comment: What about using '*' with a constant or expression?

Comment: Constants aren't _always_ assigned memory. Sometimes they'll be hardcoded into the generated instructions, such that they end up as part of the code, not the data. (obvs., this is _very_ specific to the instruction set / hardware / etc).

Comment: ...re: using `*` with a constant, I have plenty of examples coming to mind, but none of them are examples you can run in userspace on your PC running Linux or Windows or whatnot; think embedded systems where sensors' outputs are mapped to known locations.

Comment: That said, "what's the purpose of language-feature-X" questions are generally not on-topic here. They tend to be too-broad, opinion-based, etc.

Comment: What you expect from `j=&889;`? You can simply write `j = 889;`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: How is that relevant? The question does not ask about purpose or contain the word “why”. It asks what some expressions mean. That is a question about language semantics.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, ...and yet in summary, it's "can someone can give me examples[...]?" -- that's pretty clearly in a category we (in the tags I'm more active in, I can't speak to the C tag specifically) generally consider out-of-bounds.

Comment: It is not at all true that constants appearing is source code will exist somewhere in memory in the running code. The compiler is free to do so if it chooses, of course, but will not if it has no reason to, so "&5" is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression that is a value (*rvalue* in C idom) may not represent a variable with a defined lifetime and for that reason you cannot take its address.

In the opposite direction, it is legal (and common) to dereference an expression:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3}
int *pt = a + 1;      // pt points to the second element of the array

inf first = *(a - 1); // perfectly legal C
```

Dereferencing a constant is not common in C code. It only makes sense when dealing directly with the hardware, that is in kernel mode, or when programming for some embedded systems. Then you can have special registers that are mapped at well known addresses.

```
 first_byte_of_screen = *((char *) 0xC0000);     // may remember things to old MS/DOS programmers
```

But best practices would recommed to define a constant

```
#define SCREEN  ((unsigned char *) 0xC0000)

first_byte = *SCREEN;      // or even SCREEN[0] because it is the same thing
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil: thank you for those comments. Long time I had not played with *well known memory addresses*...

Answer (score 0):

`k=*6422296` means go to address number 6422296, read the content inside it and assign it to k, which is completely valid.

`j=&889` means get me the address of 889, 889 is an rvalue, it's a temporary that theoretically only exists temporarily in the CPU registers, and might never even get stored in the memory, so asking for it's memory address makes no sense.

Comment: `*6422296` is not completely valid. It violates the constraint in C 2018 6.5.3.2 2, which says “The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.”

Comment: The “temporary” (bad term, there are temporary objects in C) value 889 does not “theoretically only exists temporarily in the CPU registers.” The model of computing in the C standard uses it only as a value, without regarding to registers or any other hardware, and a C implementation might implement with or without a register—it could appear only as an immediate in an instruction that uses it directly as an operand without it ever existing in a register, or it could be folded into other operations in the expression and never exist as 889 in the generated code or data at all.

Answer (score 0):

> All constants in a program are also assigned some memory.

That's not necessarily the case for numeric literals; they're often hardcoded into the machine code instructions with no storage allocated for them.

A good rule of thumb is that anything that can't be the target of an assignment (such as a numeric literal) cannot be the operand of the unary `&` operator<sup>1</sup>.

> **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1     The operand of the unary **`&`** operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
> **`[]`** or unary **`*`** operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
> not declared with the **`register`** storage-class specifier.
> 2     The operand of the unary **`*`** operator shall have pointer type.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

`*6422296` "works" (as in, doesn't result in a diagnostic from the compiler) because integer expressions can be converted to pointers:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 5     An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
> result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
> entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.<sup>67)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>67) The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
> be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.</sup>

---

1. Like all rules of thumb, there are exceptions; array expressions are lvalues, but cannot be the target of an assignment; if you declare an array like `int a[10];`, then you can't reassign `a` such as `a = some_other_array_expression ;`.  Such lvalues are known as *non-modifiable* lvalues.